# How to properly include twitter bootstrap in electron app?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager

This is my first electron app, which is based on quick-start app. I want to add twitter bootstrap's css. So I installed it like this:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

And included in the index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

When I run: `npm start` from terminal it works fine. However when I try to build it using electron-packager like this:

```
npm run build
```

I get a native mac app "myApp.app", but when I open it, I don't see the styles.

The only files in the application aside from `node_modules` and `package.json` are: `main.js` and `index.html` and both are in the root dir.

Is there a step here that I am missing?

**Edit**

I realized that the application is looking for the css file in `Resouces/app` directory. Is it the responsibility of the build tool to include the css file, or should I include it manually? If I have to take care of this, did I even needed to install bootstrap from npm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check your `package.json` file: is `bootstrap` listed as a dependency? Probably not since it doesn't look like you are using the `--save` param:

> npm install bootstrap --save

I'm no Electron hero: I happen to be working on a project using `fs-jetpack` at the moment. I deleted the `fs-jetpack` entry from from my `project.json` and did an OSX build using `electron-packager`. On launch I got a script error about missing "fs-jetpack'. From that I conclude that the packager uses the 'package.json` to know what to include. Maybe I'm wrong? I have "--prune=true" as one of the packager params. Maybe without that it includes everything?

Also, I am surprised that this line works for you:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but perhaps you are using a different folder structure where the index.html file is not in the app directory?

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the --save option. That did the trick. As for the project structure, I am using the quick starter that comes without app folder and the index page is at root.